# Different Resources allocations for different databases on same Postgres instance

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql

I have a postgres instance with multiple databases. Can I limit the amount of resources one database (lower priority) will use, but allow the other database (higher priority) to use as many resources as it wants?

Answer (score 1):

This is a limit on Postgres itself, as mentioned [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Priorities#:~:text=PostgreSQL%20has%20no%20facilities%20to,gets%20more%20resources%20than%20others.) there is no way to prioritize resources to one database over the other. This would have to be done through the OS.

Since you are using Cloud SQL which is a managed service, you won't be able to do such things as temper with the OS in order to achieve this. If you want to do this, you would need to use a normal Compute Engine instance so you are able to manage the resources on it.

Hope you find this information useful!